# Submitting R jobs via single ssh command using nohup bash -c

Tags: r, bash, ssh

I used to work with an older university server where I could submit analysis jobs using commands like the following. The server was a bit dated and using C Shell.

```
ssh -t user@oldserver 'cd ~/hte_paper/Code; nohup tcsh -c "R CMD BATCH analysis-file1.r; R CMD BATCH analysis-file2.r" &'
```

With the Ubuntu 20.04 server images provided by the Uni I work at now, this doesn't work anymore. Neither of the following commands work, nor do any of the variations I've tried. What am I missing? I've been using these commands in Makefiles to automate some work and prefer that over using tmux.

```
ssh -t user@myserver 'cd ~/some/folder; nohup bash -c "R CMD BATCH analysis-file.r" &' 
ssh -t user@myserver 'nohup bash -c "cd ~/some/folder; R CMD BATCH analysis-file.r" &'
```

Comment: Note that `R CMD BATCH` is deprecated in favour of `Rscript`.

Comment: I've been going back to `R CMD BATCH` as there is no way to get a log file from `Rscript`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A friend helped me figure it out. The following works.

```
ssh -t user@myserver "set -m; cd ~/some/folder; (R CMD BATCH analysis-file1.r; R CMD BATCH analysis-file2.r) &"
```